# how to remove file d:\hiberfil.sys

Tags: windows-8, windows-10

I have 2 hard drives: C: and D:. D once was a system disk and contains huge file hiberfil.sys. I cannot delete it even as administrator. I tried `powercfg -h off`, but it removed c:hiberfil.sys and not D:hiberfil.sys. How can I remove  d:\hiberfil.sys?

Comment: which error message do you get when try to delete the file?

Comment: Could Not Find D:\hiberfil.sys

Comment: Try `attrib -h -s -r d:\hiberfil.sys` first.   Or use the GUI.

Comment: @Harry Johnston your command replies: Access denied - D:\hiberfil.sys

Answer (score 0):

you will probably have to take ownership of the file first and then delete it as an administrator

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753659.aspx

Comment: this receipt failed for me